# Java Script does not run on flutter_webview

Tags: javascript, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I have html file that contains CSS and script inside it. I have a slider that increases the font on slide of the slider. This works fine when directly run on web browser but when integrated with the flutter, it does not work. I am using  webview_flutter_plus to display the following content.

Here's the html file with the script for slider :

```
      <html>
        <head>
          <style type="text/css">
          body {
              margin:0;
              
              
          }
          .container { 
              position: relative;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
              width: auto;
              flex-direction: column;
              margin: 20px auto;
              
              
          }
          .container .size-slider {
              width:100%;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: flex-end;
              align-items: flex-end;
              margin-bottom:20px;
              
          }
          
          </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="size-slider">
                <input type ="range" min ="12" max="30" value="16">
                
            </div>
            <div class ="content">
                <p>मान्छे कसरी स्वस्थ छ भन्नेमा आश्चर्य लागिरहेको छ । स्वस्थ रहन भनेर हामीले फलफूल, सागसब्जी र दूधदही मात्र खान्छौँ तर पनि ती कति गुणस्तरीय छन् त ? हामीले खाने सागसब्जी र फलफूलमा पनि विषादी प्रयोग गरिएको छ । ती कुराले पनि हामीलाई पूर्ण स्वस्थ बनाउन सक्दैन । आज हामीले सेवन गरिरहेका चिजबारे हामीलाई नै थाहा छैन । न त त्यो वस्तु कहाँबाट आएको भन्ने कुरा थाहा छ न त त्यो चिज कसले बनायो भन्ने ? हामीले खाने माछामासु कति स्वस्थ छ भन्ने कुरा नै हामीले सरोकार राख्दैनौँ । हामीले खाने चिजको स्रोत त थाहा हुनुपर्‍यो नि । अहिले हामी आकर्षित विज्ञापनका नाममा गुणस्तरहीन वस्तु उपभोग गरिरहेका छौँ ।</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            
            const range = document.querySelector('input');
            const content = document.querySelector('.content');
            range.addEventListener('input',function() {
                const rangevalue =range.value;
                content.style.fontSize = rangevalue + "px";
                
            })
        </script>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue myself.While using webview or webviewplus there's a constructor named javascriptMode where you have to have the value as JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

Thank you all !

Comment: You can [edit] this answer to explain how you solved the issue. That will help future visitors to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your flutter project and find where you define your WebViewController()  and insert the ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted) option. For example:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted) // add this
  ..loadRequest(
    Uri.parse('https://www.example.com'),
  );
}
```

After you setJavaScriptMode to JavaScriptMode.unrestricted javascript will now work.